# unexpected endif line 34 don't know why

Tags: php

**parse error unexpected endif at line  i don't know why**

```
   <form name="contactform" method="post" action="check.php" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                        <?php   if(array_key_exists('errors', $_SESSION));   ?>
                     <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <?php implode('<br>', $_SESSION['errors']); ?>
                     </div>
                    <?php unset($_SESSION['errors']); ?>
                <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Your `if` ends with a semicolon (`;`), not a double colon `:`. The `endif` syntax *only* works if the `if` statement end with a double colon.

Comment: Should be `if(array_key_exists('errors', $_SESSION)) :`

Comment: And you should put an `echo` in front of your `implode()`

Comment: i it was : not ; and you know you you type faster and think what you have to do at the same time it's not easy and yes i should put echo front of implode to display errors thank you a lot

Comment: i"m sorry about that i'm no familiar with stackovrflow and i don"t know how to indent my code here but i'll learn how to use the site correctly to provide all the code for the questions in the futur and thank you anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
<?php   if(array_key_exists('errors', $_SESSION));   ?>
```

to:

```
<?php   if(array_key_exists('errors', $_SESSION)):   ?>
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Explanation:

In your code, you are putting semi-colon `;` after if statement.

It means you are closing `if` control structure, hence, `endif` below has no meaning.

If you put `:`, the code between `if` and `endif` will be considered as body of control structure and hence will not produce error.

Comment: ohhhhhh god yes small error and you will be crazy and yes it shoudl be : not ; een white my glasses i couldn't see it thank you